# SharePoint Designer 2013 - Imported Files are not viewable but says they exist

Tags: page-layout, import, file

I am the site Collection Administrator on 40 different Site Collections.

I have created 3 new Page Layouts that I would like to deploy to all sites and I have imported them to a test Site Collection using the Import Files function is SP Designer.

Upon import I don't see the files in SP Designer, however when I attempted to import files again I got a message saying that the files are existed.

Answer (score 0):

The imported files should be visible in your master pages library in SPD.

The specific location will be `../%sitename%/_catalogs/masterpage/`

Comment: Okay, I do see that now.  Any idea why these Layouts do not show up under "Page -> "Page Layouts" on the when I am editing a page?

Comment: Use the dropdown menu to publish the layout(s). You'll subsequently be able to see and select them from the location you referenced.